# Unable to get Dictionary key , value in string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have code to get json object in C# object. In `req object`, I have an object called numbers. Each number has 1 key and 3 values:

1. date
2. desc
3. status

How do I get each number's key and its  3 values?
i want number, date, desc, status fields

http://postimg.org/image/j4x36aotd/

json

```
{
    "requestId": "546b384ce51f469a2e8b4567",
    "numbers": {
        "917566559950": {
            "date": "2014-11-18 17:45:59",
            "status": 1,
            "desc": "DELIVERED"
        }
    }
}
```

C# Code

```
public partial class All_GetSmsReeport : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string json = "";
        if (Request.QueryString["data"] !="")
        {
            json = Request.QueryString["data"];

            var req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(json);
            string requestid = req.requestId;

        }
    }

}

public class smsstatus
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
}


public class Request
{
    public string requestId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, smsstatus> numbers { get; set; } //<-- See this line
}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing? Your screenshot shows the object is properly deserialized.

Comment: The program looks correctly,can you show your string `json`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385493/i-have-json-response-having-objects-with-different-names-but-all-objects-have-sa/31385793#31385793

Comment: Or you don't know how to loop the result?

Comment: Properly getting all the values , but i dnt know how to make loop to get values of a number.@ChandanRoy

Comment: @krishnamohan Then your question just boils down to how to loop over a dictionary.. the rest of the stuff about json is completely unrelated.

Comment: i dnt know making loop to get values. every number is a key and there are 3 values date,desc, status.i want to insert into db all the values / sms status .@SkyFang

Comment: Are you talking 'bt the JSON data that contains multiple request IDs and assiciated data? If so, you need to deserialize it to an array of `Request` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple forach loop iteration.

```
foreach (var numberObj in req.numbers)
        {
            var key = numberObj.Key;
            var value = numberObj.Value;

            var status = value.status;
            var date = value.date;
            var descr = value.desc;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Nikhil . can i store in string variable instead of var.@nikhil chavan

Comment: @krishnamohan Try it.

Comment: @krishnamohan - I would suggest you to read on following link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

```
var req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(json);
foreach (var kv in req.numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key:{0} Date:{1} Status:{2} Desc:{3}", kv.Key, kv.Value.date, kv.Value.status, kv.Value.desc);
}
```

How to loop

Comment: im using web application not console.write line will not  work . response.write giving errro.@sky fang

Comment: @krishnamohan Come on mate, if you're unable to figure out how to take this snippet and apply it to your code without Console.WriteLine, then you really need to read up on C# - or programming in general - before you start asking these open-ended questions which would end up with us having to completely write your app for you.

Comment: actually i used response.write and it gave error , so i asked. yes its definately simple and very basic que. but i thought that it can resolve in less time here. so i asked @rob

Comment: @Rob - Agree with you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
            Try this:
                var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject));
                foreach (var item in t.numbers)
                {
                    Console.Write(item.Key);
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Value.date + ":" + item.Value.desc + ":" + item.Value.status);
                }
```